# Bash: check job is finished

Tags: bash, jobs

Theoretical question. Can someone explain me why `jobs` keep returning `Done` when it's already done?

```
root@test:~# cat 1.sh
#!/bin/bash

sleep 5 &
while true; do
  echo $(jobs) && sleep 1
done

root@test:~# ./1.sh
[1]+ Running sleep 5 &
[1]+ Running sleep 5 &
[1]+ Running sleep 5 &
[1]+ Running sleep 5 &
[1]+ Running sleep 5 &
[1]+ Done sleep 5
[1]+ Done sleep 5
[1]+ Done sleep 5
[1]+ Done sleep 5
^C
```

`GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Because `while true` will never exit unless you `exit` yourself when the job is done or when you have reached some sort of timeout limit.

Comment: the question is not about exiting script, it's all about `$(jobs)` returning `Done` all the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because job control is disabled in scripts, bash ignores signal `SIGCHLD` and is not notified (and doesn't want to) about terminating background processes.

Because `jobs` is executed inside a subshell, the parent shell environment doesn't know that the last `jobs` already checked the child exit status and that the child terminated. Because of that, each time a new subshell is created, it's fresh environment is not aware that the message was printed, so it prints another one.

Comment: Thanks. So if you say that subshells cannot pass changes to its' parent shells then how does the subshell distinguish "Running" state from "Done"? Why `$(jobs)` is not returning "[1]+ Running sleep 5 &" all the time?

Comment: `how does the subshell distinguish "Running" state from "Done"?` ? It just checks if the pid is running. Alternatively is has a pidfd open, so it checks if the pidfd is running, either way the same.